# Como fazer scroll com 3 divs

Tags: css3, flexbox

Estou enfrentando um problema de scroll

```css
.div-pai
{
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.linha
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
} 
 
.dados
{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-pai">
        <div class="linha">
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Nessa apresentação eu tenho 3 `div`s, aonde eu preciso que a primeira (cor vermelha) ocorra scroll-x, a segunda é aonde eu recebo meus dados, e a terceira são como se fossem colunas..

Porém quando eu uso o `overflow` na primeira `div`, a segunda `div` não acompanha os dados.

Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse caso em particular não use `display: flex;` use `display: inline-block` no filho e no neto junto de `white-space: nowrap;` para evitar que os netos quebrem em linha dentro do filho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece meio confuso mas no exemplo abaixo vc pode ver que funciona e como  fica o resultado.

```css
.div-pai
{
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.linha
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
} 
 
.dados
{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-pai">
        <div class="linha">
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
            <div class="dados">teste</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```